# Generic BiFunction as parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have 3 files somewhat like so:

```
public class AConfig {
    BConfig bConfig; //assume initialized

    private B getA() {
        return bConfig.getB(this::pickWhich);
    }

    public <T> Wrapper<T> pickWhich(T a, T b) {
        //logic to decide whether to return a or b that doesn't actually use a or b
        //store a or b in c
        return new Wrapper<>(c);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class BConfig {
    CConfig cConfig; //assume initialized
    B b1, b2; //assume initialized

    public <T> B getB(BiFunction<T, T, Wrapper<T>> function) {
        C c = cConfig.getC(function);
        return createB(function.apply(b1, b2), c);
    }

    private B createB(Wrapper<B> b, C c) {
        //... 
    } 
}
```

.

```
public class CConfig {
    C c1, c2; //assume initialized

    public <T> C getC(BiFunction<T, T, Wrapper<T>> function) {
        return createC(function.apply(c1, c2));
    }

    public C createC(Wrapper<C> c) {
           //... 
    } 
}
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so I can pass down the function and use it in both methods getB and getC, but I get errors in the apply parenthesis saying "apply (T, T) in BiFunction cannot be applied to (B, B)" and the same error in getC but with "(C, C)".

I know if I change getB to

```
    public B getB(BiFunction<B, B, Wrapper<B>> function) {
        C c = cConfig.getC(function);
        return createB(function.apply(b1, b2), c);
    }
```

It will work fine, but then I can't pass the function down through the getC call.

Is there any way to keep the function generic so it can be used in both methods?

Comment: Can you add the declaration of ```createB``` and ```createC``` to the question?

Comment: Also the code does not reflect what are the types of those missing local variables (b1, b2, c1, c2). I gues they are B and C but you should make explicit.

Comment: Added more context.

Comment: Ok, the way the method are define it only make sense if T is simutaneously an instance of C and B. This can be explicitly indicated by imposing the appropriate constrain in T like so: <T extends B & C> every where you declare <T>. Try this and se what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `createB` requires as an input a `Wrapper<B>` but the only thing that is guaranteed in the current code to have is a `Wrapper<T>` where T is totally unbound (can be anything).

Same with createC it would need that the input BiFunction returns a `Wrapper<C>`.

So the problem is whether you can construct a BiFunction that would simultaneously have  a Wrapper and Wrapper return. 
If T extends B and C (so is declared as `<T extends B & C>` This seems to 
be accomplished.

However since you intent to apply the BiFunction on B and C arguments T also need to be a supper of both B and C .... so in the end T, B and C need to be the same class!!!

I think you may need to rethink your design.